# Unable to delete PST file after extracting from Outlook

Tags: .net, outlook

For some reason, I am unable to delete a PST file after I have extracted it out of Outlook using .NET code.  The code I'm using is from: [How can I create an Outlook PST file using .Net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1724789/how-can-i-create-an-outlook-pst-file-using-net).

Is there anything I can do to release the lock at the end of extracting out the PST file?  According to this post: [Problem in releasing memory from an Outlook pst file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/486883/problem-in-releasing-memory-from-an-outlook-pst-file), it holds the lock for 30 minutes.  There has got to be a way around this, isn't there?

The issue is that I need to do something else with this PST file after I have extracted it from Outlook.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the registry to override the default 30 minute lock.